# How to implement the "instagram explore page" top buttons?

Tags: ios, swift

If you open the instagram app on your mobile and go to the explorer page you can see couple of buttons on the top of the page like "IGTV", "Travel", ... The interesting part for me is that you can scroll these buttons to the left or right. My question is how do we implement this feature in swift? do we use standard buttons in a specific container or use totally different things. thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add more relevant information to your question. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Dear Muhammad Tariq, If you open the instagram app on your mobile and go to the explorer page you can see couple of buttons on the top of the page like "IGTV", "Travel", ... The interesting part for me is that you can scroll these buttons to the left or right. My question is how do we implement this feature in swift? do we use standard buttons in a specific container or use totally different things. thanks